# what happens first body onload function or PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, onload

My question is simply if i have a javascript function onload like so

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
```

will this function be executed BEFORE the PHP in the rest of the body ?

Comment: PHP runs before the markup is even sent to the browser: onload() only runs when all the markup has been sent to the browser

Comment: All the answers are correct, and a good way to think of it, if you are a beginner, is this: PHP prints "<body onload='myFunction()'>" , then the browser reads it, and runs myFunction in its javascript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

1. `onload` doesn't get executed until the entire document, including images, has been *rendered*
2. PHP runs on the *server* (before the browser receives the file)

---

It is possible for some of the output of a PHP script to arrive in the browser before the entire script has finished executing, and you could even set things up so that the HTTP response finishes before the script has finished — but that takes some complicated jiggery pokey, is rarely useful, and you should know if you've gone to such lengths.

Comment: Thanks very much , exactly what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

The function itself explains it "onLoad", so when your page is loaded ( including PHP ), your function then will be executed.